# Reading the control codes being sent by a barcode reader

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, barcode-scanner

I have an old bar code reader that is sending some control codes before and maybe after it reads the bar code.

I need a way to capture these codes so I can duplicate them on a new reader.  The current unit is so old I have no info on it or a way to get the config.

The control box is connected via RS-232 to the computer.
manual for the reader.
http://www.amltd.com/docs/M2500_user-manual.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide the model of the reader, it could help us...

In general, old bar code simulates a keybord, and some even were attached in the keyboard PS/2 connector.

If that's your case, you can read those codes using any keyboard code reader software.

If you know something about javascript, take a look [at this site](http://www.jquery4u.com/events/find-keycode-keyboard-key-press/)

If you just want a software to do that, you can download some [from here](http://www.delphiforfun.org/Programs/Utilities/KeyCodes.htm)

Comment: updated my post.